# How to override a type from a library in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an app, and I'm using `react-hook-form` to handle my forms, and it works great. The issue is that in my app, I can have multiple errors for each field, for example, I can have a password field which has 4 rules, must have a minimum amount of characters, must have at least 1 upper case, 1 lower case and 1 special character. With that in mind, when I get the error from `react-hook-form`, it will only return 1 error at a time, but I need to render all error messages instead of just 1 at a time.

Right now for the validation, I'm using `yup` to create the schema and I also created a resolver that creates an array of errors for each field, so it looks like this:

```
export const useValidationResolver = <T extends Maybe<AnyObject>>(
  schema: ObjectSchema<T>
) => {
  return useCallback(
    async (data: T) => {
      try {
        const values = await schema.validate(data, {
          abortEarly: false,
        });

        return {
          values,
          errors: {},
        };
      } catch (errors) {
        return {
          values: {},
          errors: errors.inner.reduce(
            (
              allErrors: Record<string, ValidationError[]>,
              currentError: ValidationError
            ) => {
              console.log(currentError);
              if (allErrors[currentError.path!]) {
                allErrors[currentError.path!] = [
                  ...allErrors[currentError.path!],
                  currentError,
                ];
              } else {
                allErrors[currentError.path!] = [currentError];
              }

              return allErrors;
            },
            {}
          ),
        };
      }
    },
    [schema]
  );
};
```

The resolver works, I can see the errors being passed as an array to my component, the issue is that typescript is complaining because when I try to do something like `error.map((error) => ...)`, it's not possible since the type of the error is the `FieldError` from `react-hook-form`. You can check the documentation for this type here [FieldError](https://react-hook-form.com/ts#FieldError).

So, what I want to do, is to change the `FieldError` type to instead of being just an object, to be an array of objects with the same shape, so basically instead of this:

```
export type FieldError = {
  type: string
  ref?: Ref
  types?: MultipleFieldErrors
  message?: Message
}
```

I want this:

```
export type FieldError = {
  type: string
  ref?: Ref
  types?: MultipleFieldErrors
  message?: Message
}[]
```

I was reading and looks like it's possible to achieve this by creating a `react-hook-form.d.ts` in my project and overriding the type declarations, but I couldn't really find an example that overrides just a type and nothing else.

So if anyone has an example on how to change just a single type from `react-hook-form` and leave everything else intact, that is what I'm looking for!